# Is it possible to do a svn copy that exclude a particular directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I need to take a backup of a working copy to put it in the "Tags" subfolder of this working copy. If I do svn copy it will copy the entire working copy including the "tags" subfolder. I don't want to take the "tags" subfolder.

So how do I take svn copy exclude one directory ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you didn't misspell `tags` and `Tags` (with big  `T`). In this case you can copy everything to `Tags` and before commit you should delete `Tags/tags`. And after it you can commit it.